# I need some help with a specific probability question. It's about radioactive decay.

Tags: calculus, probability

The probability that a radioactive particle will decay in the interval $0\leq t\leq T$ is

$$
P( [0,T] )=\frac{PART}{WHOLE}= \frac{1}{W} \int_0^T e^{-\ln(2)t} dt
$$

Where $W$ is $\int_0^\infty e^{-\ln(2)t} dt$ (which I evaluated to be $\frac{1}{\ln2}$).

**Q.:** What is the probability that it survives to time $t=1$, but decays some time during the interval $1\leq t\leq 2$? (Only give the integral formula and approximate it with a calculator.)

---

I gave this problem a go and reasoned that such probability would be given by:

$$
P([1,2]) = \frac{1}{W} \int_1^2 2^{-t} dt = \frac{1}{4}
$$

But this is clearly wrong, since one can evaluate such integral pretty easily, without the need for a calculator. I've reviwed the lessons on probability with little to no improvements. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you have some reason to think the integral is incorrect other than that some reference advised you to use a calculator for it?

Comment: Should say:  I don't believe that this is what the problem was looking for.  I'd say they wanted the conditional probability that the thing decays in that interval, given that it did not decay earlier (so that the answer is then $P([0,1])$ which is also easy to compute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the particle can only decay once, the probability of decay in a particular interval is equal to the expected number of decays in that interval.  Because of this, you can use linearity of expectation to write the answer exactly as you did:
$$
P([1,2])=P([0,2])-P([0,1])=\frac{\int_{1}^{2}e^{-t \log 2} dt}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t \log 2} dt}=\frac{-e^{-t\log 2}\vert_{1}^{2}}{-e^{-t\log 2}\vert_{0}^{\infty}}=\frac{2^{-1}-2^{-2}}{2^{-0}-2^{-\infty}}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
You may alternately want to use the fact that decay is a memory-less process, so the probability of decaying in any interval $[a,b]$ (conditioned on survival up to time $a$) is just a function of $b-a$.  So, since
$$
P([0,1])=\frac{1}{2},
$$
you also have $P(t\in[1,2] \;|\;t\ge 1)=1/2$, and
$$
P([1,2])=P(t\in [1,2] \;|\; t\ge 1)\cdot P(t\ge 1)=P(t\in [1,2] \;|\; t\ge 1)\cdot \left(1 - P([0,1]\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
(But note that this approach only works if the decay rate is constant over time.  Your initial approach, writing the result as an integral over the specific interval $[1,2]$, is more generally correct.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a very insightful answer.